# DataTables warning: table id=tableID - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am trying fill jquery datatable with data. it is working if number of rows are less than 4000 but not working if it is beyond that. I have tried increasing MaxJsonLength using below code.

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
var jsonModel = serializer.Serialize(Model);
```

### In view

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
    try 
    {
        var table = $('#MyPeople');
        var TransactionData = '@Html.Raw(jsonModel)';
        oTable = $(table).DataTable(
        {
            dom: '<"top">rt<"bottom"lip><"clear">',
            fixedHeader: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            sScrollX: '100%',
             stateSave: false,
             ordering: true,
              "sort": "true",
              "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
                              setTimeout(function () {
                                 $("#overlay").fadeOut("slow");
                                    }, 30)
                                },
               "processing": true, // for show progress bar
               "language": { "processing": "processing... Pleae Wait" },
                "serverSide": true, // for process server side
               "ajax": {
                          "url": '@Url.Action("LoadTransactionData", "TravelAndEntertainment")',
                           "type": "POST",
                           "datatype": "json",
                            "data": { transactionData: TransactionData },
                        },
               "columns": arrColumns,//column data
        });
    }
    catch (err) 
    {
        console.log("Error in operation! " + err);
    }
});
```

It is failing when i try to call  '@Url.Action("LoadTransactionData", "TravelAndEntertainment")', and giving error like "DataTables warning: table id=tableID - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"

**LoadTransactionData** function i have written in controller. where i am passing data and doing paging and sorting etc..

Please let me know if anybody is facing same issue and any solution is there for this issue?

Comment: Isn't this the reason we use pagination? Could also be a server error. Check your developer tools to see what the response body is as suggested by the page you refer to.

Comment: Returning 4000 rows sounds like a bit crazy.